# Help me understand Dispose() implementation code from MSDN

Tags: c#, idisposable

the following code is from MSDN: [Idisposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // If you need thread safety, use a lock around these 
        // operations, as well as in your methods that use the resource.
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing) {
                if (_resource != null)
                    _resource.Dispose();
                    Console.WriteLine("Object disposed.");
            }

            // Indicate that the instance has been disposed.
            _resource = null;
            _disposed = true;   
        }
    }
```

why  the following statement:

```
 _resource = null;  
_disposed = true;
```

are not enclosed by if (disposing) statement block?

for me i would probably write like this:

```
if (disposing) {
       if (_resource != null) {
            _resource.Dispose();
            _resource = null;
            _disposed = true;
           }
         Console.WriteLine("Object disposed.");
   }
```

anything wrong with my version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern outlined by the MSDN is the only correct way to implement IDisposable because it takes finalization into account. You need to look closely at the IDisposable implementation:

```
public void Dispose() 
{
    Dispose(true);

    // Use SupressFinalize in case a subclass
    // of this type implements a finalizer.
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);      
}
```

This calls your dispose method, indicating it's a real dispose and supresses further finalization.

It's not safe to call out to any other object during finalization, so that's why you want to set:

```
 _resource = null;  
_disposed = true;
```

to prevent any further mishappenings.

Here's a [good info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx#dotnetgcbasics_topic5) on finalization and IDisposable on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

After the call to Dispose() the resource should always be marked as disposed because otherwise you could run into problems. So even if _resource is null, you need to mark it as disposed.

Running

```
_resource = null;
```

doesn't hurt even if the resource was null at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ;)

Ok, the _resource = null - has IMHO to go in as you said. The sample code is sloppy here, sorry ;) I also prefer it your way.

_disposed = true, though, is INDEPENDENT on the existence if _resource. It should ALSO be set if the _resource pointer has not been initialized to start with, so it should go DIRECTLY above the Console.WriteLine. Imagine a situation where the _resource is a file handler, which is opened during a method call in the classs - there may be scenarios where the class is created, but the file handler not, and in this case dispose has to also function.

`if (disposing) {

    if (_resource != null) {

        _resource.Dispose();

        _resource = null;

    }

    _disposed = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Object disposed.");

}`

is how I would write it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dispose(bool)` function is usually called both from `Dispose()` and from the Finalizer (named ~Class in C#). When called by the finalizer, garbage collection is already underway, and the order of garbage collection between different objects is not defined. The garbage collector might very well have destroyed `_resource` already, so it's only when `Dispose(bool)` is called from `Dispose()` that we want to destroy "child resources" (This is true for managed resources, unmanaged resources should always be freed)

Comment: I dislike the Microsoft's use of the term "garbage collection" to include both finalization and object destruction.  If a finalizable instance `Zoo` of class `Foo` has a field called `Zar` of type `Bar` which holds a non-null object reference, the target of that reference *is guaranteed to exist* during the execution of the `Zoo.Finalize()`.  It is possible that target may have already run its `Finalize()` method, or may be scheduled to do so, or may still be in use somewhere, but in any case if `Zar` is non-null, it is guaranteed not to have been destroyed by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

The placement of the 2 lines in question is correct in the MSDN pattern

The reason is that in a correct implementation, as provided on my blog referenced below, the overloaded version of Dispose(bool) passes a value of `false` in the call from the Finalizer.  Note that you should only implement a Finalizer if you truly need one. That being said, the placement of these lines should not vary based on whether or not you implement a Finalizer.

I've written an improved version of the IDisposable pattern on my blog - [How do you properly implement the IDisposable pattern?](http://dave-black.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-do-you-properly-implement.html). You will find that my provided implementation of this pattern is slightly different than that which is posted on MSDN.  IMHO, it isn't sufficient.  You have to agree that a large number of samples and examples posted on MSDN are "hacky" and don't do things the way that they should be done in the "real world".

Comment: There are some things in Microsoft's pattern which I find disagreeable, and your code seems to follow its lead.  Most notably, if `Dispose` is called multiple times, `Dispose(bool)` will likewise get called multiple times, and since `Disposed` is private, every derived class that wants to protect against redundant disposal will need its own `Disposed` flag.  I would think it cleaner to have an `int DisposeStatus` which gets `Interlocked.Exchange`'d to 1 by the `IDisposable.Dispose` wrapper method (which should only call `Dispose(bool)` if the field had been zero.